# Caption with longtable and pgfplotstabletypeset

Tags: longtable, pgfplotstable

The 'longtable' documentation says to use

```
\caption{Your caption here}
```

for captions, but I can't see where to specify the 'longtable' options in the example where pgfplotstabletypeset and longtable is used together.

MWE: You'll see currently the Table 1 text is just included, but that would mean it would be excluded from ToC and index of tables.

```
\documentclass{article}


% MWE from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40411/import-files-with-pgfplotstable-and-split-tables-across-multiple-pages
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=4in,bottom=4in,right=1in,left=1in]{geometry} %%% change the margins in your file suitably.
\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents}{testdata.dat}
Idx  Nam Dim Grd
1   Ady 53  F
2   Bar 72  C
3   Cor 83  B
4   Dar 58  D
5   Esa 68  C
6   Foo 67  C
7   Gar 74  C
8   Hur 65  D
9   Jaz 85  B
10  Ker 91  A
1   Ady 53  F
2   Bar 72  C
3   Cor 83  B
\end{filecontents}

{\large Table 1}

\pgfplotstableset{
begin table=\begin{longtable},
end table=\end{longtable},
}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=space,
header=true,    
columns={Idx,Nam,Dim,Grd},      % display specified columns
columns/Idx/.style={fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=0,column type=r},
columns/Nam/.style={column type=l,string type},
columns/Dim/.style={fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=1,column type=r},
columns/Grd/.style={column type=l,string type},
% requires booktabs to place horiz rules
every head row/.style={before row=\toprule, after row=\midrule\endhead}, 
every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule}
]{testdata.dat}

\end{document}
```

Would I put it in the `\pgfplotstableset` or `\pgfplotstabletypeset` sections, and with what syntax?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a `longtable`, the `\caption` command needs to go into its own line in the table. In your example, you could put `\caption\\` into the `before row` key:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


% MWE from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40411/import-files-with-pgfplotstable-and-split-tables-across-multiple-pages
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=4in,bottom=4in,right=1in,left=1in]{geometry} %%% change the margins in your file suitably.
\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents}{testdata.dat}
Idx  Nam Dim Grd
1   Ady 53  F
2   Bar 72  C
3   Cor 83  B
4   Dar 58  D
5   Esa 68  C
6   Foo 67  C
7   Gar 74  C
8   Hur 65  D
9   Jaz 85  B
10  Ker 91  A
1   Ady 53  F
2   Bar 72  C
3   Cor 83  B
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableset{
begin table=\begin{longtable},
end table=\end{longtable},
}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=space,
header=true,    
columns={Idx,Nam,Dim,Grd},      % display specified columns
columns/Idx/.style={fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=0,column type=r},
columns/Nam/.style={column type=l,string type},
columns/Dim/.style={fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=1,column type=r},
columns/Grd/.style={column type=l,string type},
% requires booktabs to place horiz rules
every head row/.style={before row=\caption{Some numbers}\\\toprule, after row=\midrule\endhead}, 
every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule}
]{testdata.dat}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @Jake, I'm still wrapping my head around combining packages. So much to learn.

Comment: It's also possible to combine `\caption` with `\endfirsthead`, in case the `longtable` spans multiple pages. See chapter 2.5 *Customizing and Getting the Tabular Code* in [Manual for Package PgfplotsTable](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplotstable.pdf).

Comment: This works great with one addition and one remark. I had to put two `\\` between `\caption` and `\toprule`. Otherwise the heading would not reach completely from left to right. What should be mentioned is that the caption will be repeated on every page for a multi page document when this approach is used.