# pgfplotstable and longtable table counter problem/caption positioning

Tags: longtable, pgfplotstable

Consider the following MWE which uses `pgfplotstable` and `longtable` to output some `csv` file content. The table counter are incrementet twice for each table added. Why?

```
\begin{filecontents*}{mytable.csv}
Chem.;Avg. Conc.;Avg. Conc. Norm.; Conc. Unit;Mass sum;Mass unit
ammonium;159083,33;114450,21;\si{\micro\gram\per\liter};2839,463;\si{\kilo\gram}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs, longtable, geometry} 
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest,}
\pgfplotstableset{
begin table=\begin{longtable},
end table=\end{longtable},
%every head row/.append style={before row=\captionof{table{Caption}}
}
\usepackage{capt-of}

\begin{document}

{\centering
\captionof{table}{First table}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    header=has colnames,
    col sep=semicolon,
    read comma as period=true,
    display columns/0/.style={column type={l},string type}, 
    display columns/1/.style={sci,sci zerofill,sci sep align,},
    display columns/2/.style={sci,sci zerofill,sci sep align,},
    display columns/3/.style={column type={l},string type}, 
    display columns/4/.style={sci,sci zerofill,sci sep align,},
    display columns/5/.style={column type={l},string type}, 
]{mytable.csv}\par
}

{\centering
\captionof{table}{Second table}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    header=has colnames,
    col sep=semicolon,
    read comma as period=true,
    display columns/0/.style={column type={l},string type}, 
    display columns/1/.style={sci,sci zerofill,sci sep align,},
    display columns/2/.style={sci,sci zerofill,sci sep align,},
    display columns/3/.style={column type={l},string type}, 
    display columns/4/.style={sci,sci zerofill,sci sep align,},
    display columns/5/.style={column type={l},string type}, 
]{mytable.csv}\par
}

{\centering
\captionof{table}{Third table}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    header=has colnames,
    col sep=semicolon,
    read comma as period=true,
    display columns/0/.style={column type={l},string type}, 
    display columns/1/.style={sci,sci zerofill,sci sep align,},
    display columns/2/.style={sci,sci zerofill,sci sep align,},
    display columns/3/.style={column type={l},string type}, 
    display columns/4/.style={sci,sci zerofill,sci sep align,},
    display columns/5/.style={column type={l},string type}, 
]{mytable.csv}\par
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used `longtable` inside `table` , which does no good as `table` is a box so can not split so then a table `\caption` and `longtable` both increment the table caption.

Either just use longtable, and use `\caption` inside `longtable` or use `\caption` inside `table` and use `tabular`.

Comment: Didn't consider `table` being a box, I just added `table` to show that it happens there as well. Please see my edit. This happens also without the `table` environment, replacing `caption` with the `captionof` macro. Am I positioning the `caption(of)` wrong?

Comment: @Holene same issue with `\captionof` that increments the counter too, but in longtable, longtable itself increments the counter and `\caption` does not (so you can `\caption` repeated for headings, etc) so if you are using longtable you need to use its caption (or just set the counter back by one).

Answer (score 0):

This question already (kind of) has been answered: [Caption with longtable and pgfplotstabletypeset](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85629/caption-with-longtable-and-pgfplotstabletypeset)

The problem is the positioning of the caption, which must be added as

```
every head row/.style={before row=\caption{First table}\tabularnewline}
```

in the optional argument of `\pgfplotstabletypset` macro. `captionof` does not work (and is not needed).

```
\begin{filecontents*}{mytable.csv}
Chem.;Avg. Conc.;Avg. Conc. Norm.; Conc. Unit;Mass sum;Mass unit
ammonium;159083,33;114450,21;\si{\micro\gram\per\liter};2839,463;\si{\kilo\gram}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs, longtable, geometry} 
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest,}
\pgfplotstableset{
begin table=\begin{longtable},
end table=\end{longtable},
}
\usepackage{capt-of}

\begin{document}

{\centering
%\captionof{table}{First table}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    header=has colnames,
    col sep=semicolon,
    read comma as period=true,
    display columns/0/.style={column type={l},string type}, 
    display columns/1/.style={sci,sci zerofill,sci sep align,},
    display columns/2/.style={sci,sci zerofill,sci sep align,},
    display columns/3/.style={column type={l},string type}, 
    display columns/4/.style={sci,sci zerofill,sci sep align,},
    display columns/5/.style={column type={l},string type}, 
    every head row/.style={before row=\caption{First table}\tabularnewline}
]{mytable.csv}\par
}

{\centering
%\captionof{table}{Second table}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    header=has colnames,
    col sep=semicolon,
    read comma as period=true,
    display columns/0/.style={column type={l},string type}, 
    display columns/1/.style={sci,sci zerofill,sci sep align,},
    display columns/2/.style={sci,sci zerofill,sci sep align,},
    display columns/3/.style={column type={l},string type}, 
    display columns/4/.style={sci,sci zerofill,sci sep align,},
    display columns/5/.style={column type={l},string type}, 
    every head row/.style={before row=\caption{Second table}\tabularnewline}
]{mytable.csv}\par
}

{\centering
%\captionof{table}{Third table}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    header=has colnames,
    col sep=semicolon,
    read comma as period=true,
    display columns/0/.style={column type={l},string type}, 
    display columns/1/.style={sci,sci zerofill,sci sep align,},
    display columns/2/.style={sci,sci zerofill,sci sep align,},
    display columns/3/.style={column type={l},string type}, 
    display columns/4/.style={sci,sci zerofill,sci sep align,},
    display columns/5/.style={column type={l},string type},
    every head row/.style={before row=\caption{Third table}\tabularnewline}
]{mytable.csv}\par
}

\end{document}
```

[image]