# pgfplot table cannot compile

Tags: longtable, pgfplotstable

I am working of the post found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40411/import-files-with-pgfplotstable-and-split-tables-across-multiple-pages) that talks about importing a .dat file into latex and converting it into a table. The table that I have is a `longtable`.  I am having a problem getting my code to compile as I get the error:

"Package pgfplots Warning: running in backwards compatibility mode (unsuitable t
ick labels; missing features). Consider writing \pgfplotsset{compat=1.12} into 
your preamble.
 on input line 8."

Can you help me get my code to compile correctly?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableset{
begin table=\begin{longtable},
end table=\end{longtable},
}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=space,
header=true,
columns={theta_1,r2v,r3v,x,y},      % display specified columns
columns/theta_1/.style={fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=0,column type=r},
columns/r2v/.style={column type=l,string type},
columns/r3v/.style={fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=1,column type=r},
columns/x/.style={column type=l,string type},
columns/y/.style={column type=l,string type},
% requires booktabs to place horiz rules
every head row/.style={before row=\toprule, after row=\midrule\endhead},
every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule}
]{data.dat}

\end{document}
```

and here is my data.dat file:

```
theta_1    r2v    r3v      x      y
73.32513 0.08109 0.32216 1.07136 1.58646
81.52127 0.39714 0.18930 1.12726 1.54498
11.42881 0.15561 0.40579 2.00083 -0.25418
82.20383 0.26427 0.26641 0.98759 1.65272
56.91233 0.08282 0.17536 1.39728 1.09515
8.77864 0.30099 0.46950 2.07209 -0.48038
25.06484 0.13149 0.43797 2.02329 0.26017
49.21934 0.32704 0.27508 1.78136 0.81424
86.17562 0.34461 0.31124 0.95389 1.75653
86.83997 0.37408 0.29352 0.96191 1.74816
14.18518 0.22527 0.10387 1.73510 -0.29920
87.35335 0.04191 0.15062 0.60779 1.62930
86.14503 0.11449 0.23546 0.72013 1.69588
43.68381 0.45667 0.11524 1.82554 0.43447
72.02524 0.07619 0.42215 1.13327 1.65837
12.76977 0.41291 0.09738 1.76232 -0.52640
37.95852 0.26917 0.11296 1.74265 0.39662
82.41620 0.49807 0.08535 1.18931 1.44604
71.29866 0.03909 0.11383 1.02021 1.36372
86.35432 0.22134 0.21785 0.81945 1.67413
59.01666 0.05333 0.15555 1.32064 1.14392
3.21405 0.48095 0.46169 2.01803 -0.85916
76.42164 0.00232 0.21510 0.88239 1.55644
84.05939 0.38746 0.09241 1.03807 1.49802
61.08616 0.40865 0.45244 1.73304 1.27895
68.19661 0.43435 0.48987 1.59916 1.50884
66.88192 0.04222 0.21943 1.16654 1.37700
35.30043 0.19989 0.05556 1.67229 0.33875
58.99301 0.12994 0.12903 1.37311 1.08118
15.40680 0.40003 0.20436 1.88439 -0.40392
63.54415 0.21571 0.29745 1.43481 1.29929
2.86496 0.45532 0.13111 1.68131 -0.86237
24.92307 0.09092 0.30142 1.88300 0.23440
4.15543 0.13190 0.35561 1.90078 -0.48544
8.74186 0.07277 0.11087 1.68263 -0.31065
74.11120 0.06803 0.05871 0.96481 1.35119
62.53458 0.43465 0.14834 1.58297 1.04053
28.53895 0.28985 0.15939 1.83473 0.11008
85.51998 0.27493 0.21208 0.89672 1.65209
3.10015 0.07248 0.25393 1.78677 -0.46653
39.48699 0.42652 0.04276 1.77733 0.27689
34.34026 0.31103 0.13124 1.80291 0.26160
68.89651 0.17548 0.40051 1.30693 1.53810
71.56799 0.25662 0.01461 1.18879 1.20559
16.81853 0.20090 0.46443 2.08509 -0.09151
44.07880 0.03798 0.36517 1.71079 0.92168
40.10276 0.11996 0.24430 1.73094 0.66028
58.16817 0.06166 0.28926 1.41503 1.23344
63.84283 0.09195 0.11864 1.23811 1.20082
67.92180 0.11998 0.22942 1.21717 1.37797
24.84226 0.20863 0.48154 2.09624 0.20060
61.17324 0.02483 0.27340 1.30851 1.30980
58.95882 0.45136 0.26057 1.71697 1.02732
14.63506 0.47239 0.11580 1.81137 -0.52166
10.70979 0.24543 0.24445 1.85564 -0.39751
44.85276 0.24463 0.31203 1.80625 0.76074
86.37696 0.16886 0.33957 0.77410 1.79925
30.63472 0.45003 0.19776 1.94411 0.05883
52.67410 0.18462 0.18372 1.56041 0.93381
20.14307 0.05560 0.49399 2.06461 0.17615
67.61404 0.39013 0.01887 1.39416 1.07384
22.95856 0.19487 0.44258 2.06045 0.12907
45.53613 0.12085 0.45664 1.81001 0.97214
62.91691 0.20196 0.39809 1.48253 1.37938
80.18129 0.04823 0.04936 0.79541 1.43980
86.33623 0.06599 0.13094 0.65939 1.59706
49.24940 0.47103 0.16768 1.81990 0.63982
12.47620 0.47807 0.33986 2.01043 -0.54665
13.43646 0.28760 0.06828 1.71090 -0.39074
23.17574 0.02989 0.36061 1.91967 0.25628
75.66455 0.11739 0.05338 0.97433 1.35947
22.88540 0.17658 0.32688 1.94691 0.09829
73.28563 0.41060 0.24709 1.36645 1.41905
21.91725 0.00770 0.38953 1.94337 0.24543
83.63373 0.02151 0.35752 0.71488 1.79431
31.49854 0.08450 0.45186 1.96868 0.53257
17.69357 0.32456 0.44546 2.10576 -0.18323
22.59755 0.36586 0.16708 1.87258 -0.14765
55.44402 0.32387 0.34937 1.72210 1.06557
42.59600 0.22546 0.09890 1.66495 0.55888
31.64936 0.27350 0.01527 1.69479 0.14776
74.77458 0.14816 0.37204 1.10870 1.64356
52.67377 0.37235 0.25001 1.74989 0.87269
49.47512 0.09448 0.23996 1.57811 0.94661
82.54743 0.34339 0.45236 1.08023 1.83273
25.72551 0.09176 0.30493 1.88306 0.26153
68.14802 0.18424 0.30883 1.30092 1.43255
67.83562 0.31281 0.42972 1.47339 1.48888
34.24013 0.39011 0.40274 2.07231 0.34584
51.10395 0.04056 0.28836 1.53900 1.06260
6.82689 0.46469 0.09146 1.69863 -0.75815
4.85551 0.38786 0.11997 1.69344 -0.73716
47.77178 0.24340 0.44326 1.85245 0.94973
70.12505 0.21793 0.01434 1.18229 1.18817
84.06096 0.22339 0.24495 0.89063 1.66674
11.69156 0.15317 0.08396 1.68633 -0.30784
51.19413 0.25425 0.48934 1.82980 1.08773
42.24516 0.25539 0.35635 1.87903 0.69960
1.07119 0.40881 0.25024 1.77173 -0.86584
30.34104 0.39742 0.23554 1.95042 0.11336
```

Comment: On second thought, I don't see why you would get that error from your code, it seems to be about a plot, not a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only error I get is a `missing $ inserted` because of the underscore in the first column name. After changing that to `theta1` everything works.

That said, I wouldn't use `string type` for the last column in particular, as that has minus signs. Instead, add `dec sep align` so that the numbers are aligned at the decimal point. You can also set the `column name` to something nicer if desired.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
theta1    r2v    r3v      x      y
73.32513 0.08109 0.32216 1.07136 1.58646
81.52127 0.39714 0.18930 1.12726 1.54498
11.42881 0.15561 0.40579 2.00083 -0.25418
82.20383 0.26427 0.26641 0.98759 1.65272
56.91233 0.08282 0.17536 1.39728 1.09515
8.77864 0.30099 0.46950 2.07209 -0.48038
25.06484 0.13149 0.43797 2.02329 0.26017
49.21934 0.32704 0.27508 1.78136 0.81424
86.17562 0.34461 0.31124 0.95389 1.75653
86.83997 0.37408 0.29352 0.96191 1.74816
14.18518 0.22527 0.10387 1.73510 -0.29920
87.35335 0.04191 0.15062 0.60779 1.62930
86.14503 0.11449 0.23546 0.72013 1.69588
43.68381 0.45667 0.11524 1.82554 0.43447
72.02524 0.07619 0.42215 1.13327 1.65837
12.76977 0.41291 0.09738 1.76232 -0.52640
37.95852 0.26917 0.11296 1.74265 0.39662
82.41620 0.49807 0.08535 1.18931 1.44604
71.29866 0.03909 0.11383 1.02021 1.36372
86.35432 0.22134 0.21785 0.81945 1.67413
59.01666 0.05333 0.15555 1.32064 1.14392
3.21405 0.48095 0.46169 2.01803 -0.85916
76.42164 0.00232 0.21510 0.88239 1.55644
84.05939 0.38746 0.09241 1.03807 1.49802
61.08616 0.40865 0.45244 1.73304 1.27895
68.19661 0.43435 0.48987 1.59916 1.50884
66.88192 0.04222 0.21943 1.16654 1.37700
35.30043 0.19989 0.05556 1.67229 0.33875
58.99301 0.12994 0.12903 1.37311 1.08118
15.40680 0.40003 0.20436 1.88439 -0.40392
63.54415 0.21571 0.29745 1.43481 1.29929
2.86496 0.45532 0.13111 1.68131 -0.86237
24.92307 0.09092 0.30142 1.88300 0.23440
4.15543 0.13190 0.35561 1.90078 -0.48544
8.74186 0.07277 0.11087 1.68263 -0.31065
74.11120 0.06803 0.05871 0.96481 1.35119
62.53458 0.43465 0.14834 1.58297 1.04053
28.53895 0.28985 0.15939 1.83473 0.11008
85.51998 0.27493 0.21208 0.89672 1.65209
3.10015 0.07248 0.25393 1.78677 -0.46653
39.48699 0.42652 0.04276 1.77733 0.27689
34.34026 0.31103 0.13124 1.80291 0.26160
68.89651 0.17548 0.40051 1.30693 1.53810
71.56799 0.25662 0.01461 1.18879 1.20559
16.81853 0.20090 0.46443 2.08509 -0.09151
44.07880 0.03798 0.36517 1.71079 0.92168
40.10276 0.11996 0.24430 1.73094 0.66028
58.16817 0.06166 0.28926 1.41503 1.23344
63.84283 0.09195 0.11864 1.23811 1.20082
67.92180 0.11998 0.22942 1.21717 1.37797
24.84226 0.20863 0.48154 2.09624 0.20060
61.17324 0.02483 0.27340 1.30851 1.30980
58.95882 0.45136 0.26057 1.71697 1.02732
14.63506 0.47239 0.11580 1.81137 -0.52166
10.70979 0.24543 0.24445 1.85564 -0.39751
44.85276 0.24463 0.31203 1.80625 0.76074
86.37696 0.16886 0.33957 0.77410 1.79925
30.63472 0.45003 0.19776 1.94411 0.05883
52.67410 0.18462 0.18372 1.56041 0.93381
20.14307 0.05560 0.49399 2.06461 0.17615
67.61404 0.39013 0.01887 1.39416 1.07384
22.95856 0.19487 0.44258 2.06045 0.12907
45.53613 0.12085 0.45664 1.81001 0.97214
62.91691 0.20196 0.39809 1.48253 1.37938
80.18129 0.04823 0.04936 0.79541 1.43980
86.33623 0.06599 0.13094 0.65939 1.59706
49.24940 0.47103 0.16768 1.81990 0.63982
12.47620 0.47807 0.33986 2.01043 -0.54665
13.43646 0.28760 0.06828 1.71090 -0.39074
23.17574 0.02989 0.36061 1.91967 0.25628
75.66455 0.11739 0.05338 0.97433 1.35947
22.88540 0.17658 0.32688 1.94691 0.09829
73.28563 0.41060 0.24709 1.36645 1.41905
21.91725 0.00770 0.38953 1.94337 0.24543
83.63373 0.02151 0.35752 0.71488 1.79431
31.49854 0.08450 0.45186 1.96868 0.53257
17.69357 0.32456 0.44546 2.10576 -0.18323
22.59755 0.36586 0.16708 1.87258 -0.14765
55.44402 0.32387 0.34937 1.72210 1.06557
42.59600 0.22546 0.09890 1.66495 0.55888
31.64936 0.27350 0.01527 1.69479 0.14776
74.77458 0.14816 0.37204 1.10870 1.64356
52.67377 0.37235 0.25001 1.74989 0.87269
49.47512 0.09448 0.23996 1.57811 0.94661
82.54743 0.34339 0.45236 1.08023 1.83273
25.72551 0.09176 0.30493 1.88306 0.26153
68.14802 0.18424 0.30883 1.30092 1.43255
67.83562 0.31281 0.42972 1.47339 1.48888
34.24013 0.39011 0.40274 2.07231 0.34584
51.10395 0.04056 0.28836 1.53900 1.06260
6.82689 0.46469 0.09146 1.69863 -0.75815
4.85551 0.38786 0.11997 1.69344 -0.73716
47.77178 0.24340 0.44326 1.85245 0.94973
70.12505 0.21793 0.01434 1.18229 1.18817
84.06096 0.22339 0.24495 0.89063 1.66674
11.69156 0.15317 0.08396 1.68633 -0.30784
51.19413 0.25425 0.48934 1.82980 1.08773
42.24516 0.25539 0.35635 1.87903 0.69960
1.07119 0.40881 0.25024 1.77173 -0.86584
30.34104 0.39742 0.23554 1.95042 0.11336
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableset{
begin table=\begin{longtable},
end table=\end{longtable},
}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=space,
header=true,
columns={theta1,r2v,r3v,x,y},      % display specified columns
columns/theta1/.style={fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=0,column type=r,column name={$\theta_1$}},
columns/r2v/.style={column type=l,precision=6,dec sep align,column name={$r_{2v}$}},
columns/r3v/.style={fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=1,column type=r,column name={$r_{3v}$}},
columns/x/.style={column type=l,precision=5,dec sep align,column name={$x$}},
columns/y/.style={column type=l,precision=5,dec sep align,column name={$y$}},
% requires booktabs to place horiz rules
every head row/.style={before row=\toprule, after row=\midrule\endhead},
every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule}
]{data.dat}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your response.  How to you set the column names?

Comment: @Joe Look at my code. `column name={whatever}`.

Comment: ok, sorry...I just scrolled across and saw it...I'm working from a small screen.  Thank you!