# pgfplotstable longtabu repeating header and other options

Tags: pgfplotstable, tabu, longtabu

I want to print a long table with `pgfplotstable` and `long tabu`.  For some reason, with the following code, I do not get the header repeated on every page. I also want a `\bottomrule` and a caption on every page like "table xy (continued)".

Also, the width I specified by `\begin{tabu} to 0.6\linewidth` is ignored.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableset{
    create on use/new/.style = {create col/expr={\pgfplotstablerow+1}}} % Indices of rows
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
        outfile=table.tex,
    begin table={\begin{longtabu} to 0.6\linewidth},
    end table={\end{longtabu}},
    every head row/.style={
        before row={
            \toprule
            },
        after row={
            % Specify units in header
            & unit & unit & unit & unit & unit & unit \\
            \midrule},
    },
    every last row/.style={
        after row={
            \bottomrule
            \caption[short]{long}\\
            \label{tab:table}\\
            }
        },
    multicolumn names,
    col sep=space,
    columns={
        new,
        [index]0,
        [index]1,
        [index]2,
        [index]3,
        [index]4,
        [index]5
    },
    % Index
    display columns/0/.style={
        column name=Index,
        column type={r},
        precision=1
    },
    display columns/1/.style={
        column name=$x_1$,
        column type={S},string type},
    display columns/2/.style={
        column name=$x_2$,
        column type={S},string type},
    display columns/3/.style={
        column name=$x_3$,
        column type={S},string type},
    display columns/4/.style={
        column name=$x_4$,
        column type={S},string type},
    display columns/5/.style={
        column name=$x_5$,
        column type={S},string type},
    display columns/6/.style={
        column name=$x_5$,
        column type={S},string type}
]{DATA.txt}

\end{document}
```

Remark: My data file `DATA.txt` is loaded correctly and contains some lines like

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Comment: Can you make your example compilable?

Comment: Sorry for the extreme delay. I fixed it by adding two packages I forgot when copying out of my document: \usepackage{siunitx}, \usepackage{caption}.
Also added \\ in every last row/.style={...} to the \caption and \label command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"making the example compilable" means using `filecontents` or an inline table.

In the given example are much things which can be bunched together. If you have x-times the same command definitions, look for ways to compress them - this is LaTeX, not Word...

[image]

[image]

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex

\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.txt}
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

%\usepackage{array}
%\usepackage{caption}

%\usepackage{siunitx}

% Specify columns
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,...,5} {%
\pgfplotstableset{
columns/#1/.style = {
column name=$x_{\pgfmathparse{int(#1+1)} \pgfmathresult}$,
%column type=r, 
%column type={S},
string type
},
}}%

% Indices of rows: 
\pgfplotstableset{
create on use/IndexCol/.style = {create col/expr={\pgfplotstablerow+1}},
columns/IndexCol/.style={column type=c}, 
column name={Index}
} 

% Sepcify Long Table
\pgfplotstableset{
LongTable/.style 2 args={%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
begin table={\begin{longtabu} to 0.6\textwidth},
end table={\end{longtabu}},
every head row/.style={
before row={
\caption{#2}\\
\endfirsthead 
\midrule
\multicolumn{\ColsNo}{c}{{Table \thetable\ Continued from previous page}} \\
\bottomrule
\endhead
\midrule \multicolumn{\ColsNo}{r}{Continued on next page} \\ \bottomrule
\endfoot 
\midrule
\multicolumn{\ColsNo}{r}{{End of Table \thetable}} \\ \bottomrule
\endlastfoot 
},
after row={& #1 \\ \midrule},
},
%every last row/.style={after row={}},
%multicolumn names,
}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{My long table}

\pgfplotstablegetcolsof{\jobname.txt}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\ColsNo{\pgfplotsretval+1}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[columns={IndexCol,0,1,...,5},
LongTable={ 
{{[unit]} & {[unit]} & {[unit]} & {[unit]} & {[unit]} & {[unit]}}%
{Long Table with Data  \label{tab:DataTable}}%
},
 outfile=table.tex,
]{\jobname.txt}
\end{document}
```